# How to justify all paragraphs of the currect buffer?

Tags: fill-paragraph, paragraphs

I would like to fill justify all paragraphs in the current buffer if no region is selected. I wrote the the following function which performs this job.

Is there a better way to write this function? Is there a build-in function which performs this job?

```
(defun my-fill-buffer () 
  (interactive)
  (if (not (region-active-p))
      (save-excursion
        (mark-whole-buffer)
        (call-interactively 'fill-region))))
```

Comment: The key sequence for indenting the whole buffer is already quite short: `C-x h <tab>`. So I don't need a special command for that.

Comment: @Tobias the effect of `C-x h <tab>` and `C-x h M-x fill-region` is different. What I need is the latter.

Comment: Sorry my bad, meant `C-x h M-q`. (See doc of `fill-paragraph`: `The REGION argument is non-nil if called interactively; in that case,
if Transient Mark mode is enabled and the mark is active, call
‘fill-region’ to fill each of the paragraphs in the active region,
instead of just filling the current paragraph.`)

Comment: @Tobias Thank you for your illuminating explanation.

Comment: IOW, `C-x h` followed by `C-u M-q` will justify each paragraph in the buffer.